# How can we add multiple TXT record using host as @ in Domain Dns?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I am not good at DNS configuration. I did some research on this topic. but it seems am unable to find the best way to set up the multiple TXT records using the host as @ in my domain DNS configuration. I was able to add aws TXT record but now I am trying to add Facebook and Google domain verification code in the TXT record in a host as @. I added it with DNS configuration but Facebook and Google are not verifying my domain.
I tried added with a meta tag and HTML file but nothing is works well. Is there any suggestion from you folks will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare might be an easy way to do this, they support multiple TXT records in the root of the domain, or atleast, I haven't had any problems with it. There are also other alternatives like ClouDNS or deSec.

Almost any DNS provider should support multiple TXT records in @.